# Loading a file into an array (Read all bytes)

Tags: c#, arrays

I am currently learning to code in C#, I have made a few basic apps that just launch applications. However now I am wanting to create a save editor.

I know I have to load the save into an array in order to search for the values I believe using the File.ReadAllBytes method?

My question is how would I do this? I know I would have to create a button on a windows form for open and another for save as well as other fields to hold information but this is as far as I know..I have done some reading on File.ReadAllBytes but I am a little confused!

Comment: How would you do what exactly? Be more specific.

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: Dear what you would like to achieve? could you be more specific Please.

Comment: Apologies if I have not been very clear in my question, what I have is a PS3 save for a game, I can open the save up in a hex editor and manually change the values of various things like 'name', 'height' etc.... What I want to achieve is to create a small program that I can open the save with and then add the values so it updates the required locations on the save and then saves the save. The save also has a CRC 32 checksum so I would also need to have the program update the checksum once any changes have been made.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it will give to you an array of strings, for sample:

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("yourFile.txt");
```